# Kubuntu taskbar requires double click to open minimized window

Tags: kubuntu, taskbar

After installing updates this morning, I could not login to KDE any more ("startkde not found"). I reinstalled KDE and solved that problem.

However, something has changed, because now I have to double click on the taskbar to maximize/minimize open applications, which is really annoying!

Is there a way to go back to normal single click behaviour?

*I have Googled and checked the system settings, but found nothing that I could logically relate to this problem.*

Answer (score 0):

Ajkain was right, it was a known bug that has been fixed after today's kde and plasma upgrades. If you're using kubuntu you just need to update your packages in order to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

I have same problem about the double click on taskbar, after I have updated KDE 4 (4.11.1).

It's a bug, I have found this link

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=324470

Comment: @ajkain Can you expand this? The bug report says the bug was fixed. Has the fix not made it into some versions of Ubuntu? What do you recommend doing? Are there workarounds in the bug report that you recommend?